# How to get File Size in BASH with readable size not in bytes

Tags: command-line, bash

Here is what I have in my shell file:

```
FILENAME=/var/lib/backups/html-backup/backup-15-04-2016.tar.gz;
FILESIZE= $(ls -lah $FILENAME | awk '{ $FILESIZEINGB = $5}')
echo "Size is $FILESIZEINGB ."
```

Can you please tell me why I can not see the file size in readable form ?

It seems $FILESIZEINGB is not set and I can not see the result in the `echo` output.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set a shell variable from a child process - so setting `FILESIZEINGB` wouldn't work anyway (and it wouldn't work because that means something else in `awk` syntax).

Just use `du -h`:

```
FILESIZEINGB=$(du -h "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $1}')
```

Also:

- You shouldn't have a space after `=`.

Comment: Technically `du -h --apparent-size "$FILENAME"` would be the correct way to emulate `ls -lah "$FILENAME"`, otherwise you get the real size.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't want to use `du`:

```bsh
FILESIZE=$(ls -lah $FILENAME | awk '{ print $5}')
echo "Filesize is $FILESIZE"
```

Comment: You can simplify it by just using `ls -sh`  - and the `awk` command becomes the same as mine.,

Answer (score 2):

I found someone made an AWK one-liner, and it had a bug but I fixed it. I also added in petabytes after terabytes.

```
FILE_SIZE=234234 # FILESIZE IN BYTES
FILE_SIZE=$(echo "${FILE_SIZE}" | awk '{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s", $1, v[s] }')
```

Considering `stat` is not on every single system, I would use the AWK solution. Example; the Raspberry Pi does not have `stat` but it does have `awk`.

Comment: You mentioned that you found this and fixed a bug, but where did you find it, and what did you fix?